# How to configure Jenkins Publish over SSH to use SSH key

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh, devops, ssh-keys

Our Jenkins instance is running on a CentOS Linux 7.3.x server. I'm trying to configure an additionnal "SSH server" in Jenkins Global settings.

Jenkins can't access my private key located at "/root/.ssh/my_private_key".

- Jenkins version: 2.101
- "Publish over SSH" plugin version: 1.18

#### Jenkins UI error : Publish over SSH > SSH Servers > SSH Server > Path to key"

> ```
> No file matching: '/root/.ssh/my_private_key'
> ```

#### Jenkins UI error : Publish over SSH > SSH Servers > SSH Server > Test Configuration)

> ```
> jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to read file - filename [/root/.ssh/my_private_key] (relative to JENKINS_HOME if not absolute).
> Message: [/root/.ssh/my_private_key]
> ```

#### Publish over SSH > SSH Servers > SSH Server

**Name**
mytargethost

**Hostname**
mytargethost.tld

**Username**
remoteusername

**Remote Directory**
/home/remoteusername

**Use password authentication, or use a different key**
[x] (checked)

**Passphrase / Password**
my_private_key_passphrase

**Path to key**
/root/.ssh/my_private_key

**Port**
22

**Timeout (ms)**
300000

**Other fields**
Blank

Comment: You run Jenkins as root?  Why?

Comment: Hi @thorbjørn-ravn-andersen, you definitely pointed me to the right direction. Jenkins run as jenkins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins service being running as jenkins user, in order to configure Jenkins to connect with SSH using a private key, "Path to key" field in Jenkins global settings (Publish over SSH > SSH Servers > SSH Server) must be (relative to JENKINS_HOME):

```
.ssh/my_private_key
```

Of course, permissions on "my_private_key" must be 0600 & owner/group "jenkins:jenkins"

```
JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins
chmod 0600 ${JENKINS_HOME}/.ssh/my_private_key
chown jenkins:jenkins ${JENKINS_HOME}/.ssh/my_private_key
```

*Real path for SSH key is: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/my_private_key if JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins*